# Inverse images of images, images of inverse images of a set of vectors

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What can be said about$\ f^{-1}(f(S))$ and$\ S$, where$\ f(S):=\{f(x):x \in S\}$?

- I feel as if$\ f^{-1}(f(S))$ will be smaller than or equal in size (number of elements) to$\ S$.
- For example, if$\ f(x)=x$, then$\ f(\{-1, 0, 1, 2\})=\{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$and$\ f^{-1}(f\{-1, 0, 1, 2\})=\{-1, 0, 1, 2\}$ (same size).
- But if$\ f(x)=x^2$, then$\ f(\{-1, 0, 1, 2\})=\{0, 1, 4\}$ and$\ f^{-1}(f\{0, 1, 4\})=\{0, 1, 2\}$, which is a little bit smaller than$\ S$.

What can be said about$\ f(f^{-1}(U))$ and$\ U$, where$\ f^{-1}(U):=\{x \in X:f(x) \in U\}$?

- The same size as each other? Always??

Comment: For your second example, $f^{-1}(\{0, 1, 4\}) = \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$ (assuming the domain and codomain of $f$ is the whole number line), which is _larger_ than $S$.

Comment: You should be specifying the domain and codomain when talking about a function.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in S$ then $f(x) \in f(S) $. Therefore, $x \in f^{-1}(f(S))$ that is $S \subset f^{-1}(f(S))$. The reverse side is not always true as you take $S=\{1\}$ and $f(x) = x^2$, then $f^{-1}(f(S))= \{1, - 1\}$.
For the second part $f(f^{-1}(U) ) \subset, U$. Take $y \in f(f^{-1}(U))$ that is $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(U)$. So $y \in  U$ and we get  $f(f^{-1}(U) ) \subset U$. Again other side is not always true as take $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ given by $f(x) =x^2$. Let $U= \{1, - 1\}$. So we have $f(f^{-1}(U))= \{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2$, then$$f^{-1}\bigl(f\bigl(\{-1,0,2\}\bigr)\bigr)=f^{-1}\bigl(\{0,1,4\}\bigr)=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$$In this case, the number of elements increases. Actually, that's what happens always; that is $\#f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)\geqslant\#S$. That's because there's an injective function from $S$ into $f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)$:$$\begin{array}{ccc}S&\longrightarrow&f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)\\x&\mapsto&x.\end{array}$$Or, if you prefer, bacause $S\subset f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)$.

Now, about $f\bigl(f^{-1}(S)\bigr)$ what it can be said is that $\#f\bigl(f^{-1}(S)\bigr)\leqslant\#S$. And it can be smaller. For instance, if $S\cap\operatorname{im}f=\emptyset$, then $f\bigl(f^{-1}(S)\bigr)=\emptyset$, even if $S\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Some rules:

- $S\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$
- $S=f^{-1}(f(S))\iff f(S)\cap f(S^{\complement})=\varnothing$
- $f(f^{-1}(U))\subseteq U$
- $f(f^{-1}(U))=U\iff U\subseteq\mathsf{im}f$

Try to verify this yourself and ring a bell if you get stuck.