# Proof of functions and their inverses in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

While self studying with the book, “Real Analysis: A Long Form Mathematics Textbook by Jay Cummings” I found the following question:

> Suppose $f : X \to Y$, $A \subseteq X$, and $B \subseteq Y$. Prove that $f(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq B$ and find an example for which $f(f^{-1}[B]) \neq B$ as well as an example for which $f(f^{-1}[B]) = B$.

The book does not come with an answer key, and the question stumped me.

Comment: I apologize for my poor communication skills; but yes, this is the question I tried to ask

Comment: Yes, thank you. I’m still new to the website so thank you for helping me type the symbols

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse images of images, images of inverse images of a set of vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551928/inverse-images-of-images-images-of-inverse-images-of-a-set-of-vectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example take a non-surjective function, eg. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2, B=\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(f^{-1}(B)) =[0,\infty)\neq B$. For the second example take the same $f$ but with $B = [0,\infty)$.

To show $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ note that any element of $f^{-1}(B)$ is mapped to $B$ by $f$.